# Column aggregation in linux

Tags: file, bash, sed, awk, aggregation

I have huge text file of such format:

```
aaa bbb 1      
aaa ccc 2      
aaa ddd 3      
bbb ww 1      
bbb kio 3
```

I want to aggregate it and the result should be:

```
aaa bbb 1/6  
aaa ccc 2/6  
aaa ddd 3/6  
bbb ww 1/4  
bbb kio 3/4
```

3rd column - probability p(y|x)

How should I do that using awk, sed?

Comment: Assuming x is the first column and y is the second, the third column in the output is not the probability of the pair (x, y). Rather, it is the conditional probability of y given x, P(y | x).

Comment: yes, you're right, sorry for mistyping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]+=$3;next}{printf("%s/%d\n",$0,a[$1])}' ./infile ./infile
```

#### Output

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]+=$3;next}{printf("%s/%d\n",$0,a[$1])}' ./infile ./infile
aaa bbb 1/6
aaa ccc 2/6
aaa ddd 3/6
bbb ww 1/4
bbb kio 3/4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two passes.  Generate *a.tmp* using:

```
{ total[$1] += $3}
END {for (group in total) {print group, total[group]}}
```

That creates a temporary file with the group totals:

```
bbb 4
aaa 6
```

Then make a second pass with:

```
BEGIN {
    while ((getline line < "a.tmp") > 0) {
        split(line, fields, " ")
        group[fields[1]] = fields[2]
    }
    close("a.tmp")
}
{   printf("%s/%d\n", $0, group[$1]) }
```

That produces the output you're looking for:

```
aaa bbb 1/6
aaa ccc 2/6
aaa ddd 3/6
bbb ww 1/4
bbb kio 3/4
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk 'func p(){for(x=0;x<c;x++)printf("%s/%d\n",l[x],t);k=$1;t=c=0};BEGIN{k=$1};$1!=k{p()};{l[c++]=$0;t+=$3};END{p()}' file
aaa bbb 1/6
aaa ccc 2/6
aaa ddd 3/6
bbb ww 1/4
bbb kio 3/4
```

N.B. Assumes file is pre-sorted by key.